# Como salvar o style inline em uma variável?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso atribuir para alguma variável o style inline de uma div, antes dela ser modificada:

O exemplo abaixo é o que eu espero que aconteça, porém eu não posso forçar **'top', '100px'** no segundo botão e sim recuperar o valor original que está dentro do style inline da div **box**.

```js
$('.top-1000').click(function(){
  $('.box').css('top','200px');
});

$('.back-100').click(function(){
  $('.box').css('top','100px');
});
```

```css
body{
position:relative;
}
.box{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="top: 100px;">

</div>

<button class="top-1000">Go</button>
<button class="back-100">Go back</button>
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, pode explicar um pouco mais?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro, basta guardares o valor da propriedade que queres antes de qualquer alteração, usando a versão `getter` do método [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```js
var original_val = $('.box').css('top'); // <-- acrescentar isto
$('.top-1000').click(function(){
  $('.box').css('top','200px');
});

$('.back-100').click(function(){
  $('.box').css('top',original_val); // <-- repor original_val
});
```

```css
body{
position:relative;
}
.box{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" style="top: 100px;">

</div>

<button class="top-1000">Go</button>
<button class="back-100">Go back</button>
```